# Pass value from HTML dropdown menu to GAS function and update another HTML dropdown menu

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I have a Google Web App that accesses text from a spreadsheet depending on dropdown selections. I'd like the "Grade" dropdown list to update it's options depending on what's selected in the "Role" dropdown menu. The way I have thought about doing it is by using indexOf to search the spreadsheet for the value selected in the "Role" dropdown and then return the values from the column with that "header".

It works if I set the indexOf manually, like so: `columnNeeded = data.indexOf('Senior') + 1;` but of course I'd like it do be done automatically, like so: `columnNeeded = data.indexOf(rolesTest) + 1;`

It seems like the issue is in passing the selected value from the "Roles" dropdown to the valuesForGradesList function.

Anyone got any clues on how to solve this? :)

Thanks in advance!

[image]

**GAS:**

```
var url = "URL";

function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
  .evaluate()
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  
}

//get the data for the "Domain" dropdown list
function valuesForList(list) {
  
  //define the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var subProjectsSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  
  subProjectsSheet.getRange('C1').activate();
  subProjectsSheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  var lastRow = subProjectsSheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex();
  var subProjectsRange = subProjectsSheet.getRange(1, 3, lastRow, 1);
  
  //create a named range
  ss.setNamedRange('subProjectsList', subProjectsRange);
  
  //get the values from the range
  var listValues = ss.getRangeByName(list).getValues();
  
  return listValues;
   
}

//get the data for the "Role" dropdown list
function valuesForRolesList(roles) {
  
  //define the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var rolesSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  rolesSheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  rolesSheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  var lastRow = rolesSheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex();
  var rolesRange = rolesSheet.getRange(1, 4, lastRow, 1);
  
  //create a named range
  ss.setNamedRange('rolesList', rolesRange);
  
  //get the values from the range
  var rolesValues = ss.getRangeByName(roles).getValues();
  
  return rolesValues;
   
}

//get the data for the "Grade" dropdown list
function valuesForGradesList(grades, rolesTest) {
  
 //define the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var gradeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  gradeSheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  gradeSheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  var lastRow = gradeSheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex();

  var columnNeeded;
  var data;
   
  lastColumn = gradeSheet.getLastColumn;

  data = gradeSheet.getRange(1,1,1,11).getValues();

  data = data[0];

  columnNeeded = data.indexOf(rolesTest) + 1;

  console.log(rolesTest);

  var gradeRange = gradeSheet.getRange(1, columnNeeded, lastRow, 1);
  
  //create a named range
  ss.setNamedRange('gradesList', gradeRange);
  
  //get the values from the range
  var gradesValues = ss.getRangeByName(grades).getValues();
  
  return gradesValues;
 
   
}

//the function to show the "Team" data on the index.html
function PostInfo (userInfo){
  
  //load the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Domain specific"); 
  var data = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  
  var domainList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]});
  var domainDesc = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]});
  
  var position = domainList.indexOf(userInfo.subprojects);
  if(position > -1){
    
    return domainDesc[position]; 
  }   
}

//the function to show the "Role" data on the index.html
function PostRoles (rolesInfo, userInfo){
  
  //load the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Role specific"); 
  var data = ws.getRange(4,1,ws.getLastRow(),8).getDisplayValues();
    
  var roleList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]});

  var roleSummary = data.map(function(r){return r[1].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  var roleBullets = data.map(function(r){return r[2].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  var roleTasks = data.map(function(r){return r[3].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  var roleQualificationsSummary = data.map(function(r){return r[4].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  var roleQualificationsBullets = data.map(function(r){return r[5].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  var roleMandateSummary = data.map(function(r){return r[6].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  var roleMandateBullets = data.map(function(r){return r[7].replace(/{craftname}/g, userInfo.subprojects);});  
  
  var position = roleList.indexOf(rolesInfo.roles);
  var results = [roleSummary[position], roleBullets[position], roleTasks[position], roleQualificationsSummary[position], roleQualificationsBullets[position], roleMandateSummary[position], roleMandateBullets[position]];
  
  if(position > -1){
    
    return results; 
           
  }   
}

//function to load external Javascript page
function include(filename){

return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css"> 
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th>
      <label for="subprojects"><b>Domain:</b></label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label for="role"><b>Role:</b></label>
    </th>
    <th>
      <label for="grade"><b>Grade:</b></label>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>
      <select name="subprojects" id="subprojects" tabindex="2"></select>
    </th>
    <th>
      <select name="role" id="role" tabindex="2"></select>
    </th>
    <th>
      <select name="grade" id="grade" tabindex="2"></select>
    </th>
    </tr>
    <p id="test" name="test"></p>
    </table>
    <br><br>
    <div>
        <button id="btn">Generate</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="btn_pdf">Save as PDF</button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="canvas_div_pdf">   
       <p id="title" class="title" name="title"></p>
       
       <label for="est"><b><span id="name" name="name"></span></b></label>
       <p id="est" name="est"></p>
       
       <label for="respons"><b><span id="responsTag" name="responsTag"></span></b></label>
       <p id="respons" name="respons"></p>
      
       <label for="responsBullets"><span id="responsBulletsTag" name="responsBulletsTag"></span></label>
       <p id="responsBullets" name="responsBullets"></p>
       
       <label for="responsTasks"><span id="responsTasksTag" name="responsTasksTag"></span></label>
       <p id="responsTasks" name="responsTasks"></p>
       
       <label for="qualSummary"><b><span id="qualSummaryTag" name="qualSummaryTag"></span></b></label>
       <p id="qualSummary" name="qualSummary"></p>
       
       <label for="qualBullets"><span id="qualBulletsTag" name="qualBulletsTag"></span></label>
       <p id="qualBullets" name="qualBullets"></p>
       
       <label for="mandateSummary"><b><span id="mandateSummaryTag" name="mandateSummaryTag"></span></b></label>
       <p id="mandateSummary" name="mandateSummary"></p>
       
       <label for="mandateBullets"><span id="mandateBulletsTag" name="mandateBulletsTag"></span></label>
       <p id="mandateBullets" name="mandateBullets"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?!= include("javascript"); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
    
    function onListSuccess(list) {
    
      var listLength = list.length;
      
      for (i=0; i<listLength;i++) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("subprojects");
        
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        
        dropdown.options.add(opt);
        
        opt.text = list[i][0];
        opt.value = list[i][0];
              
      }
    }   
    
    function onRolesListSuccess(roles) {
    
      var rolesLength = roles.length;
      
      for (i=0; i<rolesLength;i++) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("role");
        
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        
        dropdown.options.add(opt);
        
        opt.text = roles[i][0];
        opt.value = roles[i][0];
              
      }
    } 
    
    function onGradesListSuccess(grades) {
    
      var gradesLength = grades.length;
      
      for (i=0; i<gradesLength;i++) {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("grade");
        
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        
        dropdown.options.add(opt);
        
        opt.text = grades[i][0];
        opt.value = grades[i][0];
              
      }
    } 
       
    function onListSelect(domainDesc){
    
    var name2 = document.getElementById("subprojects").value;
    
    document.getElementById('est').innerHTML = domainDesc;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'About the ' + name2 + ' team';  
    }
    
    function onRolesListSelect(results){

    var roleText = document.getElementById("role").value;
    var teamText = document.getElementById("subprojects").value;

    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = roleText + " " + teamText;

    document.getElementById('respons').innerHTML = results[0];
    document.getElementById('responsTag').innerHTML = 'Responsibilities';  
    
    document.getElementById('responsBullets').innerHTML = results[1];
    document.getElementById('responsBulletsTag').innerHTML = 'You are also:';  
    
    document.getElementById('responsTasks').innerHTML = results[2];
    document.getElementById('responsTasksTag').innerHTML = 'Example work tasks:';  
    
    document.getElementById('qualSummary').innerHTML = results[3];
    document.getElementById('qualSummaryTag').innerHTML = 'Qualifications';  
    
    document.getElementById('qualBullets').innerHTML = results[4];
    document.getElementById('qualBulletsTag').innerHTML = 'You are also:';  
    
    document.getElementById('mandateSummary').innerHTML = results[5];
    document.getElementById('mandateSummaryTag').innerHTML = 'Mandate';  
    
    if (roleSummary[6] == "") {} else {
    document.getElementById('mandateBullets').innerHTML = results[6];
    document.getElementById('mandateBulletsTag').innerHTML = 'You are also:';  
    }
    }

  
  
  document.getElementById("role").addEventListener("change", gradeUpdate); 
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
  document.getElementById("btn_pdf").addEventListener("click", getPDF);
  
  function gradeUpdate(){
  
   var rolesTest = {};
   
   rolesTest = document.getElementById("role").value;
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onGradesListSuccess).valuesForGradesList(rolesTest);
   document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = rolesTest; 
  
  }

  function doStuff(){
  var userInfo = {};
  var rolesInfo = {};
  
  userInfo.subprojects = document.getElementById("subprojects").value;
  rolesInfo.roles = document.getElementById("role").value;
 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onListSelect).PostInfo(userInfo);
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onRolesListSelect).PostRoles(rolesInfo, userInfo);
  
  
  }

 function getPDF(){

        var HTML_Width = $(".canvas_div_pdf").width();
        var HTML_Height = $(".canvas_div_pdf").height();
        var top_left_margin = 15;
        var PDF_Width = HTML_Width+(top_left_margin*2);
        var PDF_Height = (PDF_Width*1.5)+(top_left_margin*2);
        var canvas_image_width = HTML_Width;
        var canvas_image_height = HTML_Height;
    var roleText = document.getElementById("role").value;
    var teamText = document.getElementById("subprojects").value;
        
        var totalPDFPages = Math.ceil(HTML_Height/PDF_Height)-1;
        
        html2canvas($(".canvas_div_pdf")[0],{allowTaint:true}).then(function(canvas) {
            canvas.getContext('2d');
            
            console.log(canvas.height+"  "+canvas.width);
                        
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt',  [PDF_Width, PDF_Height]);
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, top_left_margin,canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
                        
            for (var i = 1; i <= totalPDFPages; i++) { 
                pdf.addPage(PDF_Width, PDF_Height);
                pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPG', top_left_margin, -(PDF_Height*i)+(top_left_margin*4),canvas_image_width,canvas_image_height);
            }
            
            pdf.save(teamText + " " + roleText);
        });
    };

  function populateList(){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onListSuccess).valuesForList('subProjectsList');
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onRolesListSuccess).valuesForRolesList('rolesList');
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onGradesListSuccess).valuesForGradesList('gradesList');

  }  
  window.addEventListener('load', populateList);
</script>
```

Comment: Here's an old example: https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/dependant-dropdowns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- In your Javascript, at `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onGradesListSuccess).valuesForGradesList('gradesList')` and `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onGradesListSuccess).valuesForGradesList(rolesTest)`, one argument is used. But at Google Apps Script, `function valuesForGradesList(grades, rolesTest) {}` is used. In this case, 2 arguments are used. And, `rolesTest` is not declared here. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- And, I thought that when I saw `valuesForGradesList` of Google Apps Script side, `grades` might be `'gradesList'`. I think that this might be also the reason of your issue. About this, if you want to use other named range, please modify it.
- By the way, in your script, when the selected value of `Role` is not existing at `Data` sheet, I thought that an error occurs.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `valuesForGradesList` as follows.

```
function valuesForGradesList(rolesTest) {  // <--- Modified

 //define the data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  var gradeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  gradeSheet.getRange('E1').activate();
  gradeSheet.getCurrentCell().getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  var lastRow = gradeSheet.getCurrentCell().getRowIndex();

  var columnNeeded;
  var data;
   
  lastColumn = gradeSheet.getLastColumn;

  data = gradeSheet.getRange(1,1,1,11).getValues();

  data = data[0];

  columnNeeded = data.indexOf(rolesTest) + 1;

  console.log(rolesTest);

  if (columnNeeded == 0) return;  // <--- Added

  var gradeRange = gradeSheet.getRange(1, columnNeeded, lastRow, 1);
  
  //create a named range
  var grades = 'gradesList';  // <--- Added
  ss.setNamedRange(grades, gradeRange);  // <--- Modified
  
  //get the values from the range
  var gradesValues = ss.getRangeByName(grades).getValues();
  
  return gradesValues;
 
   
}
```

#### Javascript side:

Please modify `onGradesListSuccess` as follows.

```
function onGradesListSuccess(grades) {

  if (!grades) return;  // <--- Added

  var gradesLength = grades.length;
  
  for (i=0; i<gradesLength;i++) {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("grade");
    
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    
    dropdown.options.add(opt);
    
    opt.text = grades[i][0];
    opt.value = grades[i][0];
          
  }
}
```

### Added:

When you want to update the dropdown list instead of the addition when `Role` is selected, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify `onGradesListSuccess` at Javascript as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onGradesListSuccess(grades) {

  if (!grades) return;  // <--- Added

  var gradesLength = grades.length;
  
  var dropdown = document.getElementById("grade");  // <--- Added
  dropdown.innerHTML = "";  // <--- Added

  for (i=0; i<gradesLength;i++) {
    
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    
    dropdown.options.add(opt);
    
    opt.text = grades[i][0];
    opt.value = grades[i][0];
          
  }
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you so much! Do you know how I can also refresh the "Grades" dropdown list everytime the values change? Right now they all get added on top of each other in the list.

Comment: @mikhga Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, I added one more modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: A follow up, right now, the "Grade" dropdown doesn't list any values until "Role" dropdown is changed. Can I set it so that when the page loads, "Grade" dropdown is updated using the default value in the "Role" dropdown?

Comment: @mikhga Thank you for replying. I'm glad your additional issue was also resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Will do! Thanks for all of your help @Tanaike!